# Cannot troubleshoot the reason why I get 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
for i in range (0,20,1): 
        df  = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name=i,sep='\s*,\s*')
        print('sample:',i+1)

        df1 = df.loc[0:50] #initial push

        ma=df1['Latest: Potential (V)'].values.tolist()
        max_force_initial_push=max(ma)
```

And when I run it, I get the following `error`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-e56ce0a5f5fd> in <module>
     45         ma=df1['Latest: Potential (V)'].values.tolist()
     46         print ('ma: ', ma)
---> 47         max_force_initial_push=max(ma)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

When I `print ma`, I get the following Result:

`ma:  [3.25836181641, 3.26812744141, 3.22906494141, 3.18023681641, 3.10729980469, 3.08776855469]`

Can someone help me to troubleshoot the problem? I don't really understand what is going on

Thanks!

Any Help Will Be Appreciated!

Comment: What if you print max?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have already tried that and I get the exact same error

Comment: You won't get the same error because we want you to do `print(max)` before this line. Not `print(max(ma))`. You overwrote `max` somewhere and it's a list now, not a method.

Comment: @h4z3 yes, I misunderstood what I was being asked, sorry about that! But as I mentioned down as reply to other answers, I was 100% that I had not defined ```max```anywhere else in my code. The problem is solved now, thanks anyway for all the kind help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error message your getting is saying that you are trying to use a 'list' object as a function
Have you defined `max` anywhere in your script? I have made this mistake many times

Comment: but isn't max() a python in-built list method max that returns the elements from a list with maximum value? Why do I need to define it? I have not  defined ```max```before, so I don't think I have overridden the function

Comment: Im not saying you should define it. If you have a variable named 'max', that will produce the error your having. If you posted a runnable code section which produces the error I could better help you

Answer (score 0):

I am coding in Jupyter notebook. Apparently, rebooting the notebook helped to solve the issue. I don't understand what happened, as I had never defined `max`before in my script. Thanks a lot for all the kind help anyway!!